# I18n translation of model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I cannot figure out how to translate model data in Rails (3.0.1) with I18n.

Example Situation:

I have a form where a registrant selects their sport. The sport select is a dropdown populated by calling:

```
Sport.all.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id]}
```

I'm tempted to naively write:

```
Sport.all.collect{ |s| [t(s.name), s.id]}
```

But I don't see how rails would know to search for names like "Track and Field". How would I provide the names in different languages? What are best practices for implementing this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Sport` is a model in the database, you'd be better off keeping translations in the database as well. Add a `language` column to your Sport model and populate with

```
Sport.where(:language => I18n.locale).collect{|s| [s.name, s.id]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most proper way is to use [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3)

If the globalize gem raises mass assignment error during `db:migrate`, then add following code to your initializer:

```
Globalize::ActiveRecord::Translation.class_eval do
  attr_accessible :locale
end
```